# Need a script to make vpn persistent in bash

Tags: linux, bash, loops, openvpn, parrot-os

So I'm on  Hack The Box and at times the VPN isn't actually connected to a host after being away or doing some other tasks that may mess with the connection. I just need help making a bash script that will.

1. ping a previously specified IP address.
2. Run the command again to restart the VPN
3. Ping the IP address in the background persistently or every few seconds and give a message if the connection is lost.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might get better help if you can show what you've attempted.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service where you can publish rough specifications and get developers to code that to you for free. StackOverflow is a community where developers helps each-other help themselves with sharing knowledge. Your post asks for code and does not show any effort to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

This should could you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=...
interval=30

function restart_vpn() {
  ...
}

while :
do
  ping -c $ip > /dev/null || restart_vpn
  sleep $interval
done
```

Not sure what "Hack The Box" is but you might be able the determine the state of your vpn in a more direct way than via ping. For instance on Linux, you might get an interface, and you can check on that with `ip link`.